# How to print the length of an array in AssemblyScript / Near?

Tags: assemblyscript, nearprotocol

I'm experimenting with simple assembly scripts on near and cannot seem to find a way to print the length of an array. Here's the smallest repro:

```
  let a = new Array<string>();
  logging.log(a.length.toString());
```

Doesn't compile with

```
ERROR TS2339: Property 'toString' does not exist on type 'i32'.

   logging.log(a.length.toString());
                        ~~~~~~~~
 in assembly/main.ts(171,23)
```

While `toString()` clearly exists on `i32`, e.g. the following snippet compiles and works:

```
  let a: i32 = 5;
  logging.log(a.toString());
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that assemblyscript type resolver cannot resolve certain kind of expressions, but this issue has been fixed here https://github.com/AssemblyScript/assemblyscript/pull/726 in upstream assemblyscript. We will fix this for smart contracts when we update the compiler. For now, the workaround is to use a temporary variable:

```
let a = new Array<string>();
let l = a.length;
logging.log(l.toString());
```